# Web admin tool provider managment

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership, provider

I have a problem with the access rules in the web admin tool

I set the rules for some pages to be accessed by the admin and deny access for the other users , but it deny access for all users including the admin !

Then , I check the provider in the web admin tool and I get this problem

> Could not establish a connection to the database. If you have not yet
>   created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration
>   tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and
>   configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the
>   provider.

Here is the code for web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="Golden_RoseConnectionString3" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Desktop\database\Golden_Rose.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />



  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>



    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Guest/login.aspx" />
    </authentication>



    <siteMap defaultProvider="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap"  name="CustomerSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>

        <add siteMapFile="~/Web1.sitemap"  name="AdminXmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />

      </providers>
    </siteMap>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>

    <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>

  </system.codedom>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

How can I fix this ?!!

Comment: Did you run the aspnet_regsql to create and configure the database?

Comment: @JackMarchetti yes I did